# MYSQL Optimising JOINED UNION SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I've re-written this query a few times now (it's Monday) with the attempt of finding the most efficient way of getting the data I require however I'm not sure I'm even approaching it correctly at the moment.

**To summarise the problem;**

Users have two sets of tags (`key_terms`, `project_terms`), there's a link table between each of these between `users` and `tags` tables.

I would like to pull out any users that have specified tags in either table. *Ideally it'd also include the 'most relevant' tag to that user - but lets put that aside for now.*

users

```
| id | name |
| 1  | dayjo |
| 2  | stackoverflow |
```

tags

```
| id | tag  |
| 1  | tag1 |
| 2  | tag2 |
```

user_key_term

```
| user_id | tag_id |
| 1       | 1      |
| 1       | 2      |
| 2       | 1      |
```

project_key_term

```
| user_id | tag_id | 
| 1       | 3      |
| 2       | 3      |
```

What I want to be able to query on is the named tags, i.e if I search for "tag1" both users should be returned, however if I search for "tag2" only  User 1 should be returned.

**My Solutions**

I tried by selecting users, and joining tags twice (one for each link table), this seemed to work ok but wasn't sure it was the best way, and couldn't figure out how to get the most relevant tag.

```
SELECT t1.tag, t2.tag as most_relevant_tag, users.* FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_key_term ON user_key_term.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN tags t1 ON user_key_term.tag_id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN project_key_term ON project_key_term.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN tags t2 ON project_key_term.tag_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.tag IN ('tag1','tag2') OR t2.tag IN ('tag1','tag2')
GROUP BY users.id;
```

My next attempt was a UNION select, but this one feels dirty;

```
SELECT users.*  FROM 
    `users`
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT project_key_term.user_id, tags.id, tags.tag FROM project_key_term
        JOIN tags ON tags.id = project_key_term.tag_id AND tags.tag IN ('tag1')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT user_key_term.user_id,tags.id, tags.tag  FROM user_key_term
        JOIN tags ON tags.id = user_key_term.tag_id AND tags.tag IN ('tag1')
        ) tags ON tags.user_id = users.id
    WHERE tags.tag IN ('tag1')
    GROUP BY users.id;
```

**But**

I've tried running EXPLAIN on both queries to see which is best, but it doesn't reveal anything particularly useful to me. Especially because at the moment there's not a lot of data in the tables, there will potentially be hundreds / thousands of tags.

Any help on the 'correct' or best practice way to do this sort of query would be great!

Comment: You could merge the two key_term tables and add a type column to differentiate. If a tag can only appear in one of these tables, you could add the type column to tag instead and only have one key_term table.

Comment: Yeah, that certainly could be an option! The 'project' table actually has another field 'project_id'. I figured to keep the ORM nice and tidy they should be separate as they'll be managed (somewhat) separately. It'd make it much quicker, and I'd only have a single JOIN. I'll certainly consider it, though, you know, why not have ALL link tables in one table with a 'type' field and generic 'table1_id', 'table2_id' fields? ;)

Comment: Ah ok. In your UNION statement you can actually remove the `WHERE tags.tag IN ('tag1')` from the outer SELECT as it is redundant.

Comment: @Arth Yeah I figured it was useless :)

Answer (score 0):

The `union` query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT users.*  
FROM users
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT user_id,tag_id 
        FROM project_key_term
        UNION ALL
        SELECT user_id,tag_id 
        FROM user_key_term
        ) alltags ON alltags.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN tags t on t.id = alltags.tag_id
where t.tag IN ('tag1')
```

Edit: Getting the most relevant tags

```
 SELECT score, t.tag, users.* 
 FROM users
 INNER JOIN (select user_id, tag_id, count(*) as score 
             from (SELECT user_id,tag_id 
                   FROM project_key_term
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT user_id,tag_id
                   FROM user_key_term
                   ) alltags
             group by user_id,tag_id) tagcounts ON tagcounts.user_id = users.id
 INNER JOIN tags t on t.id = tagcounts.tag_id
 where t.tag IN ('tag1','tag2','tag3')
 ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Ah yes, certainly looks better thanks :). Will the fact that the UNION results be much larger in your version before they're filtered have much of an affect on performance? Any opinion on whether the UNION is the 'best' way to go?

Comment: all i can say is this eliminates joining with the tags table twice. Performance depends on the indexes you have defined on those tables.

Comment: Any suggestions on being able to return the 'most relevant' tag for each user? I tried COUNT in the UNION queries, and if I group by tag, and user id in the main query it pulls out each tag and their count for each user, however Ideally this would only select the highest relevance. The only way I could figure out how to do it was with another parent query around the entire thing and some extra groups. i.e.; https://gist.github.com/Dayjo/873025ab31be311fc501ff14766fa79b - However, getting that to work with Laravel 3 eloquent is tough :D

Comment: how do you define 'most relevant tag' for a user?

Comment: User has 'tag1, tag2' in their user_key_term, and 'tag1, tag3' in project_key_term, therefore 'tag1' is the most relevant as it occurs the most for that user